# GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching not caching my eloquent query with eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, caching, eloquent

I came across this library https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching and trying to use it in a project of mine.

Firstly, I've added the following line to my `.env`:

```
MODEL_CACHE_STORE=file
```

*I am using file cache store to test, in production I will use redis.*

Then I've created `app/CacheableModel.php` with the following:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use GeneaLabs\LaravelModelCaching\Traits\Cachable;

abstract class CacheableModel extends Model
{
    use Cachable;
}
```

and then I've updated all my models (except for `app/User.php`) like this example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Company extends CacheableModel
{
    ...
}
```

and I tested it using a test route like this:

```
Route::get('test', function() {

    $testUser = \App\User::where('email', 'test@domain.com')
        ->with('company.users', 'company.subscription')
        ->first();

    dump($testUser->toArray());

});
```

When I visit test route, I can see the data loaded and dumped. If I refresh the page, it doesn't seem to be caching to be caching the above query.

I verified that it's not caching my eloquent queries by looking at the query log (using laravel telescope) as well as looking at `storage/framework/cache/data` - it's empty.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Is this not caching because `app/User.php` model doesn't use the `CacheableModel` base class and the test query starts from the user model?

Comment: I think you used `use Cachable;` is not caching from eloquent. Try with the demo code from https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching and then test it. Maybe you found what was the issue! Also, please read below line from docs: `Exception: User Model`  https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching#exception-user-model

Comment: Please try with other models except for the `User` model. Hope it will work!